# Github Action different between release created and published

Tags: npm, versioning, package.json, github-actions, git-tag

since *Github Release*s are actually a *Git Tag*s, I want to auto-upgrade my `package.json` version when there is a new Release (and tag), with *Github Action*.

I know I need to trigger a `job` `on: release`, but according to [Github Actions docs](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/events-that-trigger-workflows#release-event-release) I don't know if I need to trigger when `created`, `published`, both or all?

Github says:

> **Note:** The `release` event is not triggered for `draft` releases.

And I created two pipelines: one `on: release, type: created` and one `on: release, type: published`.

Then I **created** a `draft` release, and then I **published** it.

Only the `published` pipeline triggered, and it was when I **published** the release.

Comment: [Github Community Forum](https://github.community/t5/GitHub-Actions/What-is-the-created-type-in-on-release/m-p/41171)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

My experience has been the opposite of what was described [here on the forum](https://github.community/t5/GitHub-Actions/What-is-the-created-type-in-on-release/m-p/41171). When tested:

- If the release is created from "Draft a new release" button on the `/releases` page, both events will trigger, as the release goes from state "draft" to "published".
- If the release is created by scripts like [`release-it`](https://github.com/release-it/release-it#readme), bypassing "draft" stage and becoming "published" directly, only `release:published` will trigger

So apparently a release can be published without being created. Weird indeed. I'd go with `published`.

Answer (score 13):

In case you are trying to capture the creation and publishing of a release triggered from a Github Action into another workflow, then it is not gonna work.

The solution is to unify both workflows into a single one so that after the release is created the next workflow continues.

Source: https://twitter.com/ethomson/status/1183838077166477316

Example:

```
name: Create Release and Publish

# Trigger the create release workflow
on:
  push:
    tags:
      - 'v*'

jobs:
  release:
    name: Create Release
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Create Release
        id: create_release
        uses: actions/create-release@v1
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        with:
          tag_name: ${{ github.ref }}
          release_name: Release ${{ github.ref }}
          draft: false
          prerelease: false

  publish-gpr:
    needs: release # After release is created then run the second workflow
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: 10
          registry-url: https://npm.pkg.github.com/
      - run: npm ci
      - run: npm publish
        env:
          NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN}}
```

Comment: Why not use:
`on:
    release:
      types: [ created ]`

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky When you use the repository's `GITHUB_TOKEN` to perform tasks, events triggered by the `GITHUB_TOKEN`, with the exception of `workflow_dispatch` and `repository_dispatch`, will not create a new workflow run.

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/triggering-a-workflow#triggering-a-workflow-from-a-workflow

Answer (score 3):

A release can be created but not published. This is the case for *draft* releases.

I would suggest going with the `published` type of release.

Comment: See the link in my question. Github says "**Note:** The `release` event is not triggered for `draft` releases". But I'm going to check this.

Answer (score 0):

After I checked out the differences between them here:

https://docs.github.com/en/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads#release

[image]

And a note from here: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#release.

[image]

Although the documentation doesn't explicitly say so, I'm guessing that `created` should only take effect when creating a pre-release/release on the GitHub browser UI.

This also matches the conclusion of the top-vote answer. The `created` must go through the draft phase to be triggered.